# How can i find the local folder that iv'e marked as a drive

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using the `SUBST` command to map my folder as a drive with the use of `%CD%`

After some time I figured out I needed to know the previous path before it became a specifiv drive and no idea how to get it.

```
subst T: /d

subst T: %CD%\VMSC_OFP_P1
```

And I want to know the full path of T and maybe save it as a variable or as a `txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Going to use:

```
SUBST > path.txt
```

to get the full path in a txt file